# Secure a Spring Webflux controller considering dynamic parameters with Spring Security annotations

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-webflux

I have an application with some controllers that require access control based on the requested resources ids, checking against the Spring Security user Authentication roles. At the moment I have created a function that checks this condition returning a `Mono<True>` if it is ok (so that I can flatmap it) or an empty Mono (and also setting a 403 status code) otherwise:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/clients/{clientId}/departments/{departmentId}/users")
class UserRestController(private val userService: UserService) {

    @GetMapping
    fun getAll(principal: Principal, response: ServerHttpResponse,
               @PathVariable clientId: String, @PathVariable departmentId: String): Flux<Users> {
        return checkDepartmentViewPermissions(principal, response, clientId, departmentId)
                .flatMap {
                    userService.getAll(clientId, departmentId)
                }
    }

    ...
}

fun checkDepartmentViewPermissions(principal: Principal, response: ServerHttpResponse, 
         clientId: String, departmentId: String): Mono<Boolean> {
    val authentication = principal as MyAuthentication
    authentication.authorities.contains(SimpleGrantedAuthority("${clientId}:${departmentId}")).toMono()
            .filter {
                it == true
            }.switchIfEmpty {
                response.statusCode = HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN
                Mono.empty()
            }
}
```

As seen above, requests are in the format `/api/v1/clients/{clientId}/departments/{departmentId}/users` where `clientId` and `departmentId` are dynamic path variables.

The `checkDepartmentViewPermission` method accesses the `Authentication` roles where users will have a list such as (`client1:department1, client1:department2, client2:department1`). Thus, a URL `/api/v1/clients/client1/departments/department1/users` would work fine for those permissions.

Although what I have works, I would like to use a more declarative way to deal with this if it is possible, ideally something based on Spring Security annotations and having into account I need to access PathVariable parameters, something like (I'm making it up):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/clients/{clientId}/departments/{departmentId}/users")
class UserRestController(private val userService: UserService) {

    @PreAuthorize("#{principal.roles.contains(clientId:departmentId)}")
    @GetMapping
    fun getAll(principal: Principal, response: ServerHttpResponse,
               @PathVariable clientId: String, @PathVariable departmentId: String): Flux<Users> {
        return userService.getAll(clientId, departmentId)
    }

    ...
}
```

Does Spring Security support a way to do this?
If not, could you suggest any ideas to achieve it?

Comment: you can access method input parameters in Spring EL by prefixing their names with `#` as in `#departmentId` so try `#{principal.roles.contains(#clientId, #departmentId)}` you can write your own spring bean and call it in Spring EL `#{accessUtil.contains(#clientId, #departmentId)}`

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.10.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-ref-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, thanks Thomas for pointing me in the right direction, I hadn't realized [we can invoke a Spring bean from the security web expressions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.0.RC1/reference/htmlsingle/#el-access-web-beans). This way, there's no need anymore to inject the principal since the `Authentication` object will be passed to the bean.

**Controller**:

```
   @PreAuthorize("@permissionChecker.hasDepartmentViewPermissions(authentication, #clientId, #departmentId)")
    @GetMapping
    fun getAll(@PathVariable clientId: String, @PathVariable departmentId: String): Flux<Users> {
        return userService.getAll(clientId, departmentId)
    }
```

PermissionChecker bean:

```
class PermissionChecker {

    fun hasDepartmentViewPermissions(authentication: Authentication, clientId: String, projectId: String): Boolean {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: glad i could help.